# Understanding a DDMS Log

Tags: android, ddms

Can someone please explain how to understand a logcat from an android force close.

This crash occurs when I called finish() in the onPause().

Here is the DDMS screenshot http://www.2ql.net/uploads/1245827534.png

Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The exception is `SuperNotCalledException`. This occurs when, in various callbacks, you do not chain upward to the superclass. `onPause()` is one of those callbacks.

So, if your `onPause()` looks like:

```
@Override
public void onPause() {
  finish();
}
```

that would raise this exception. It should look like:

```
@Override
public void onPause() {
  super.onPause();
  finish();
}
```